# Field is not writeable: Quote__c.Name

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

the fields below are roll-up summary, how should I write the code to avoid the error.

```
Quote__c testQuote = new Quote__c (
        Name = '',
        Quote_Total_Value__c = '',
        LoadQuoteAmount__c = '',
        Renewal_Status__c = ''
    );
    insert testQuote;
```

Comment: I am guessing the name is an auto-number value and you should simply remove `Name = ''` from this quote record creation. I'm not sure what else you mean around the rollup summary...

Comment: I removed but its the same case for 'Quote__c.Quote_Total_Value__c = ''' as well

Comment: Like Fred mentioned, do an empty insert, instead of initializing the roll-up fields

Comment: Since it's tagged as a unit-test, you would probably have to create child records for which the roll-up is calculated against for you to use it in a test.

Comment: Thank you guys, the issue solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the line: `Name = '',`

The Name field on Quote is not writeable. I assume that is because it is an Auto-Number field.

If the other fields are rollup summary fields, then you also cannot populate them.

Just do:

```
Quote__c testQuote = new Quote__c();
insert testQuote;
```